# Laravel wild card routing upto a particular level

Tags: laravel, url, routes, wildcard

I have a **Laravel** application that I am working on and for a particular part of the application I am using wildcard routing. The *route* setup looks like this.

```
Route::get('/learn/{path?}','LearnPageController@index')
       ->where('path', '.+');
```

So, it captures all the url parts that come after learn i.e., url like

```
learn/something
learn/something/something
learn/something/something/something
learn/something/something/something/something
learn/something/something/something/something/something
.....
```

almost everything that comes after `learn/`

But I want to capture *url parts* only upto 4 level i.e.,

```
learn/something/something/something
```

and any url more than 4 level must be redirected to a 404 page.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `where` method accepts regex. I fiddled something on regex101.com:

```
Route::get('/learn/{path?}','LearnPageController@index')
   ->where('path', '/^([^\/]+\/){0,2}[^\/]+$/');
```

[Link to regex101 fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/lG7CLN/1/tests)

Look at the tests in the link above to see if it fits your needs. I just used the export method to copy+paste the regex into your php code.